# Why is my controller not firing my function.js script

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have `function.js` script which includes `onClickClear()` and `onValidate()` functions, but they are not firing at all. I injected the `loginCtrl` in the function but it still does not fire the `onClickClear()` and `onValidate()` functions. Here is the `function.js` code which clears text boxes and adds validation and my `main.cshtml`:

```
var app = angular.module('HelloWorld', []);
app.controller("loginCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.onClickClear = function () {
        $scope.UsernameTxtBox = "";
        $scope.passwordTxtBox = "";
        $scope.rememberMeCheckBox = "";
    };

    $scope.onValidate = function () {
        return ($scope.UsernameTxtBox != "" && $scope.UsernameTxtBox != null) &&
        ($scope.passwordTxtBox != "" && $scope.passwordTxtBox != null);
    };
});

    <body ng-app="HelloWorld">
        <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-push-5">
                        <h3>Login</h3>
                    <p>
                        Username:<br />
                        <input type="text" autofocus name="UsernameTxtBox" ng-model="UsernameTxtBox" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20" placeholder="Username" required>
                        <span style="color: red" ng-show="form1.UsernameTxtBox.$error.minlength">Userame Should Contain Atleast 3 Characters</span>
                        <span style="color: red" ng-show="form1.UsernameTxtBox.$error.maxlength">Limit Exceeded</span>
                    </p>
                    <p ng-bind="name"></p>
                    <p>
                        Password:<br />
                        <input type="password" name="passwordTxtBox" ng-model="passwordTxtBox" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <span style="color: red" data-ng-show="form1.passwordTxtBox.$error.minlength">Password Should Contain Atleast 3 Characters</span>
                        <span style="color: red" data-ng-show="form1.passwordTxtBox.$error.maxlength">Limit exceeded</span>
                    </p>
                    <p ng-bind="surname"></p>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="rememberMeCheckBox" data-ng-disabled="!onValidate()">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-success btn-sm" data-ng-click="onClickClear()" ng-disabled="!onValidate()">Clear</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-ng-click="onClickLogin()" ng-disabled="!onValidate()">Login</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs" data-ng-click="onClickOpen()">Not A Member? Register</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. This code seems fine, other then that UsernameTxtBox and PasswordTxtBox are undefined.

Comment: Yes the code is fine. It works in my previous application. I do not know why it doesn't work on this one.

Comment: If you know this code is fine, then why are you posting it? Post the code that isn't working

Comment: The code isn't working the way it's supposed to. Like I said, It doesn't fire onClickClear() and onValidate()

Comment: @LeboneMcdonald is there any error in console?

Comment: @pankajparkar: No. There is no error in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you do, but the example is working in code snippet...  It's basically cut and paste from your code and I just change body tag to div and add the two input box for username and password.

```js
var app = angular.module('HelloWorld', []);
app.controller("loginCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.onClickClear = function () {
        $scope.UsernameTxtBox = "";
        $scope.passwordTxtBox = "";
        $scope.rememberMeCheckBox = "";
    };

    $scope.onValidate = function () {
        return ($scope.UsernameTxtBox != "" && $scope.UsernameTxtBox != null) &&
        ($scope.passwordTxtBox != "" && $scope.passwordTxtBox != null);
    };
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app="HelloWorld">
        <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-push-5">
                        <h3>Login</h3>
                        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" ng-model="UsernameTxtBox" placeholder="Username"></div>
                        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="passwordTxtBox" placeholder="Password"></div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="rememberMeCheckBox" data-ng-disabled="!onValidate()">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-success btn-sm" data-ng-click="onClickClear()" ng-disabled="!onValidate()">Clear</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-ng-click="onClickLogin()" ng-disabled="!onValidate()">Login</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs" data-ng-click="onClickOpen()">Not A Member? Register</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Code does run in code snippet. I changed the body tag to div, but it still doesn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: There must be something else outside the script that is preventing it to run... And you sure there is no error whatsoever in console?  Javascript on?

Comment: The only message in the console is "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
(program):250 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."

Comment: Check your `<script src='...'>` tag that include angular?  Maybe there is 2 of them? or maybe angular is already in a bundle (concat and minified)?  If so, try remove one of them?  Or do you have a code somewhere that tries to bootstrap angular in script and via ng-app directive?  do you have multiple ng-app directive on the page?

Comment: I removed one of the <script src...> tags that include angular, but it still doesn't seem to work. I'll restart my project and run it again to see whether it will work or not.